# Android GPS values into Editbox

Tags: android, gps, splash-screen

**The Problem:**
I have a splash screen and its set to 5 sec. to start the "main menu"

Splash screen starts, finding gps value but it showing it on Toast message, but I want to store it in Editbox.

Splash screen have xml --> **starter.xml**

Gps Value's ( lat and lng ) editboxes have xml --> **gps_values**

**The Code:**
This is a class called starter :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.starter);


        LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
            @Override
            public void gotLocation(Location location){

                EditText lat_view = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lat_Field);
                EditText lng_view = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lng_Field);

                Double lat_source = location.getLatitude();
                Double lng_source = location.getLongitude();

                lat_view.setText(lat_source.toString());
                lng_view.setText(lng_source.toString());

                Log.d(TAG, "GPS values =" + lat_view + lng_view); 

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Latitude: "+location.getLatitude()+"\n Longitude: "+location.getLongitude() ,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
   }
        };
        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
        myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);

       final Starter sPlashScreen = this; 

        mSplashThread =  new Thread(){
@Override
public void run(){
    try {
        synchronized(this){
            wait(5000);

        }
    }
        catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
    }

    finish();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(sPlashScreen,DashboardMain.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();                   
}    };
```

**As I said**

lat_view and lng_view is on XML file called **gps_values** and there is another xml for splash activity it called **starter.xml**. Anyone can see what I cant see?

Comment: It would be helpful if you have the actual names, how do we know how `R.layout.starter` relates to `XML File 1` and `XML File 2`?

Comment: ah you are right, sry iam editing it right now